# Isn't Composition bad for testability?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, oop

Typically Composition and Aggregation are treated the same? But they are different and the choice which one to use changes a lot?
For e.g:

I believe aggregation would be ideal for testing. But composition is not.

Maintenance of dependencies is a pain while using aggregation but less using Composition.

So are there any similar views about the same? which one to choose, should it be only based on "part-of" and "has-a".

Comment: As for testing, you mean that you can't stub out a subobject using composition?

Comment: Isn't a similar harness necessary for testing in either case? I don't see how "stubbing out" can be made easier by this design choice. (I don't see the point in artificial tests for classes that only work as tightly integrated subcomponents, either.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: If any object's public interfaces are tested for all scenarios, the unit is complete, now if u want to integrate this unit with some other object why unit-test cases should be bothered about how u are using it. Since in all cases u already know the output. I am not saying mock everything avoid it in cases where its an overhead, but there are cases where if the dependency chain is huge or difficult to simulate in test environment u would want to do it.

Comment: @aeh: I'm having trouble with the run-on sentences. The issue is how small a "unit" can be. Aggregation allows for smaller units, which I gather is the advantage you see in it. I'm advocating larger units, if you're having trouble implementing meaningful tests for the small stuff.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The problem with larger units is the number of conditions to handle in a unit grows exponentially considering what they are composed of. The other issue is there is no standard justification for "how large".

Comment: @aeh: So, write a boilerplate test and specialize by templates, polymorphism, or reusing a single instance of the larger object to push the buttons of the subcomponent. There's no standard for "how large" but subcomponents that must be split off and changed to work by aggregation are a reasonable standard for "too small."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Also, [there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation, i.e. points-to, has-a-handle, has more degrees of freedom than composition, i.e. contains.

Things that can go wrong with aggregation: The subobject is destroyed too soon, it leaks, the link was never established, another object thinks it has exclusive ownership and modifies it.

Typically composition is easier for the compiler to check (such as in C++) and easier for you to check as well, as there are fewer possible uninitialized states and fewer possible means of corruption.

In general, prefer composition.

**Edit:** The *ease of writing* tests is less important than the *number of tests* necessary for good coverage. If your testing strategy causes you to make design decisions that increase failure modes, then it's working in reverse.

Unit testing notably doesn't expose flaws in integration. You're better off testing the subobject by a subsuite of tests on the client object. Document how each test delegates particular behavior to the subobject and how it is therefore tested, effectively and accurately, in its natural environment.

Of course, I know there are a lot of managers out there who will have nothing less than 1000 lines of thumb-twiddling code that does nothing but bind up and corrupt the overall design.

Comment: Don't you think the test-cases start bloating up with unnecessary information.

Answer (score 0):

The definition followed for my post is as per [here](http://ootips.org/uml-hasa.html), as there are multiple definitions of association, aggregation and composition.

I feel each has it's own use:

Aggregation: Used by Object Adapter Design Pattern

Composition: Used by Composite Design Pattern

Association: Used by Many Design Patterns e.g. Observer

It is really context dependent.

Coming to testing, I think it is easier to test components which are more loosely coupled. Aggregation promotes design which are comparatively more losely coupled than those which are based on aggregation. Since testing requires configuring code components with experimental/test supplied objects. I would say that aggregation is better. You have the flexibility of configuring objects with different test objects.

Comment: You have to choose. Don't u feel testing is required in every context.

Comment: @aeh: i am not sure how you got the impression that testing is not requried in every context. If you can point out the specific portion in my response, I will try to rectify it.

Comment: @chubsdad: The point is if you are saying that you prefer aggregation while testing, then i am not sure about the point of context dependent usage (I feel each has it's own use).

Answer (score 0):

If you unit test the elements forming the composition to demonstrate stand-alone correctness, then when testing the composed unit, you only need test the composed unit functionality and need not worry about the test coverage that applies to the composed elements.

That is to say, if you test bottom-up there may be no problem regarding testability.  When testing the composition elements, you stub the composed unit (with a test harness), not the other way around. Test of the composed units then uses the concrete units rather than stubs.

Comment: Thats one perspective. But don't you think as the number of objects go  deeper, you would have to setup your test-cases with more and more test-data, as u go up the ladder, which is a kind of a overdo.